# Install Custom Connector To Kafka Connect on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm running the kafka kubenetes helm deployment, however I am unsure about how to install a custom plugin.

When running custom plugin on my local version of kafka I mount the volume `/myplugin` to the Docker image, and then set the plugin path environment variable.

I am unsure about how to apply this workflow to the helm charts / kubernetes deployment, mainly how to go about mounting the plugin to the Kafka Connect pod such that it can be found in the default `plugin.path=/usr/share/java`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the last few slides of https://talks.rmoff.net/QZ5nsS/from-zero-to-hero-with-kafka-connect. You can mount your plugins but the best way is to either build a new image to extend the `cp-kafka-connect-base`, or to install the plugin at runtime - both using Confluent Hub.